# PancakeSwap charges a fee to mint LP according to their code?

Tags: pancakeswap, liquidity-provider, amm

I am looking at the PancakeSwap contract for LP's and I noticed they charge a fee for creating LP's.  No where in their documentation does it say there is a fee for depositing liquidity.  What is PancakeSwap doing here?  Are they giving themselves LP tokens only if I over deposit Token 0 (amount0) relative to Token 1 (amount1) in the below line of code?

```
liquidity = Math.min(amount0.mul(_totalSupply) / _reserve0, amount1.mul(_totalSupply) / _reserve1);
```

BSC Contract: 0xddE420cbB3794ebD8FFC3Ac69F9c78e5d1411870

[image: PCS LP Fee]

```
 // if fee is on, mint liquidity equivalent to 8/25 of the growth in sqrt(k)
    function _mintFee(uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1) private returns (bool feeOn) {
        address feeTo = IPancakeFactory(factory).feeTo();
        feeOn = feeTo != address(0);
        uint _kLast = kLast; // gas savings
        if (feeOn) {
            if (_kLast != 0) {
                uint rootK = Math.sqrt(uint(_reserve0).mul(_reserve1));
                uint rootKLast = Math.sqrt(_kLast);
                if (rootK > rootKLast) {
                    uint numerator = totalSupply.mul(rootK.sub(rootKLast)).mul(8);
                    uint denominator = rootK.mul(17).add(rootKLast.mul(8));
                    uint liquidity = numerator / denominator;
                    if (liquidity > 0) _mint(feeTo, liquidity);
                }
            }
        } else if (_kLast != 0) {
            kLast = 0;
        }
    }

    // this low-level function should be called from a contract which performs important safety checks
    function mint(address to) external lock returns (uint liquidity) {
        (uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1,) = getReserves(); // gas savings
        uint balance0 = IERC20(token0).balanceOf(address(this));
        uint balance1 = IERC20(token1).balanceOf(address(this));
        uint amount0 = balance0.sub(_reserve0);
        uint amount1 = balance1.sub(_reserve1);

        bool feeOn = _mintFee(_reserve0, _reserve1);
        uint _totalSupply = totalSupply; // gas savings, must be defined here since totalSupply can update in _mintFee
        if (_totalSupply == 0) {
            liquidity = Math.sqrt(amount0.mul(amount1)).sub(MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY);
           _mint(address(0), MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY); // permanently lock the first MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY tokens
        } else {
            liquidity = Math.min(amount0.mul(_totalSupply) / _reserve0, amount1.mul(_totalSupply) / _reserve1);
        }
        require(liquidity > 0, 'Pancake: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY_MINTED');
        _mint(to, liquidity);

        _update(balance0, balance1, _reserve0, _reserve1);
        if (feeOn) kLast = uint(reserve0).mul(reserve1); // reserve0 and reserve1 are up-to-date
        emit Mint(msg.sender, amount0, amount1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get an answer on Telegram from PancakeSwap.

[image]

[image]